# Not display NULL value in multi-axis chart

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I am using multi-axis chart from Highcharts.

It works fine but I don't want to display my variable if it’s NULL , where should I put the test on the NULL value ?

I have done it in a pie chart but now with all this arrays  I am lost

[image]

my multi-axis chart function which took an array composed of years and 4 arrays:

```
public function multiAxeChartDyn($date, $list1, $list2,$list3,$list4)
{
    $dates = $date;

    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('containerMultiaxe'); // The #id of the div where to render the chart
    $ob->chart->type('column');
    $ob->title->text('Budget');
    $ob->xAxis->categories($dates);

    $ob->legend->enabled(true);

    $dataSeries= array(
        $list1,
        $list2,
        $list3,
        $list4,

    );


        $yData = array(
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'formatter' => new Expr('function () { return this.value + " %" }'),
                'style'     => array('color' => '#AA4643')
            ),

            'title' => array(
                'text'  => 'Taux',
                'style' => array('color' => '#AA4643')
            ),
            'opposite' => true,
        ),
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'formatter' => new Expr('function () { return this.value + " mDT" }'),
                'style'     => array('color' => '#4572A7')
            ),
            'gridLineWidth' => 0,
            'title' => array(
                'text'  => 'Budget',
                'style' => array('color' => '#4572A7')
            ),
        ),
    );

    $ob->yAxis($yData);
    $formatter = new Expr('function () {
             var unit = {
                 "Budget": "mDT",
                  "Ressource": "mDT",
                 "Taux  global": "%",
                 "Taux Consumption": "%"
             }[this.series.name];
             return this.x + ": <b>" + this.y + "</b> " + unit;
         }');
    $ob->tooltip->formatter($formatter);

    $ob->series( $dataSeries);
    return $ob;

}
```

my controller :

```
public function indexAction(Survey $survey)
{
    $chart=new ChartController();
    $ent = $survey ->getEnt();


    $year= $survey->getYear();
    $qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('e')
        ->from('AppBundle:Survey, 'e')
        ->where('e.year <= :year')
        ->andWhere('e.ent = :ent')
        ->setParameter('year', $year)
        ->setParameter('ent', $ent->getId())
        ->orderBy('e.year', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(4);
    $survey_year =  $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    $date = array();

    $data1  = array();
    $data2  = array();
    $data3  = array();
    $data4  = array();

$survey_year= array_reverse($survey_year, true);
foreach($survey_year as $ea){
    $date[] = $ea->getyear();
    $data1[] = $ea->getForm ()->getBudget()/1000;
    $data2[] = $ea->getForm ()->getRessources()/1000;
    $data3[] = $ea->getForm ()->getTauxGlobal ();
    $data4[] = $ea->getForm ()->getTauxConsumption ();
}

$list1= array(
    'name' => 'Budget',
    'type'  => 'column',
    'color' => '#4572A7',
    'yAxis' => 1,
    'dataLabels' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'data' => $data1
);
$list2 =  array(
    'name' => 'Ressource',
   'type'  => 'column',
    'color' => '#D49EDA',
    'yAxis' => 1,
    'dataLabels' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
   'data' => $data2
);

$list3= array(
    'name' => 'Taux  global',
    'type'  => 'spline',
    'color' => '#0A0F19',
    'dataLabels' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'data' => $data3
);
$list4 =  array(
    'name'=> 'Taux Consumption',
    'type'  => 'spline',
    'color' => '#225824',
    'dataLabels' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'data' => $data4
);

$containermultiaxe=$chart->multiAxeChartDyn($date, $list1, $list2,$list3,$list4);

$html =  $this->render('AppBundle:Charting:index.html.twig',array(
        'survey' =>$survey,
        'containerMultiaxe' => $containermultiaxe,

    ));


    return $html;
}
```

Comment: which value is null?

Comment: $list1 ,$list2 ,$list3 and $list4 are for array each could contain 4 variables all could have the NULL value

Comment: try emptying your array of null values. `$array = array_filter($array);`